# Listings package : Increase spacing between = in ==

Tags: spacing, listings

Everything is in the title. The minimal example below

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% set the default code style
\lstset{
    frame=tb, % draw a frame at the top and bottom of the code block
    tabsize=4, % tab space width
    showstringspaces=false, % don't mark spaces in strings
    numbers=left, % display line numbers on the left
    commentstyle=\color{green}, % comment color
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}, % keyword color
    stringstyle=\color{blue!60} % string color
}


\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,breaklines]
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int a = 1;
  if ( a == 1 )
    cout << "Hello world" << endl; 
  return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

produces the following output

[image: Minimal example showing the == output]

I find the spacing between = in the == operator too small. Therefore I would like to increase it. How can I do that ?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you tried to literate it to add some space?

Comment: What do you mean by literate ?

Comment: It should be possible to `\lstset{literate={=}{{=\,}}1}`.

Comment: This doesn't work, but I've slightly modify it to \lstset{literate={==}{{=\,=}}1}. The problem is now the spacing between 'a' and '==' is to small :/

Comment: See my updated answer (code).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to increase the “base width”, since `=` is wider than the default 0.6em. If we do a measurement, we find that 0.6em for the standard font is about 6.57pt, whereas the width of the “=” glyph is about 8.52pt (but it has side bearings). So a base width of 0.8em seems necessary.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% set the default code style
\lstset{
    frame=tb, % draw a frame at the top and bottom of the code block
    tabsize=4, % tab space width
    showstringspaces=false, % don't mark spaces in strings
    numbers=left, % display line numbers on the left
    commentstyle=\color{green}, % comment color
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}, % keyword color
    stringstyle=\color{blue!60}, % string color
    basewidth=0.8em,
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,breaklines]
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int a = 1;
  if ( a == 1 )
    cout << "Hello world" << endl; 
  return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd much prefer `basicstyle=\ttfamily`, though.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% set the default code style
\lstset{
    frame=tb, % draw a frame at the top and bottom of the code block
    tabsize=4, % tab space width
    showstringspaces=false, % don't mark spaces in strings
    numbers=left, % display line numbers on the left
    commentstyle=\color{green}, % comment color
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}, % keyword color
    stringstyle=\color{blue!60}, % string color
    columns=fullflexible,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,breaklines]
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int a = 1;
  if ( a == 1 )
    cout << "Hello world" << endl; 
  return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution is to use `literate` as in the following example:

[image: listing]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% set the default code style
\lstset{
    frame=tb, % draw a frame at the top and bottom of the code block
    tabsize=4, % tab space width
    showstringspaces=false, % don't mark spaces in strings
    numbers=left, % display line numbers on the left
    commentstyle=\color{green}, % comment color
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}, % keyword color
    stringstyle=\color{blue!60}, % string color
    literate = { == }{{~=\,=~}}4
}


\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,breaklines]
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int a = 1;
  if ( a == 1 )
    cout << "Hello world" << endl; 
  return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Renaud This is a solution to only influence that specific group of characters in a very individual way. Probably egreg's more general solution will help you for other chars as well.

Comment: I've saved both solutions in a specific file just in case I have to use it again some day. And I've marked egreg's solution as the most relevant since it's the most general. But once again, thank you!

Comment: @Renaud You're welcome. If you like both solutions consider marking them as useful (pen up).